# Can't access a collection of objects in a Class using foreach loop

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I have a class of Customer, which has a collection of LineItem. In my main program I have a collection of customers. I use a foreach loop to iterate through the collection of customers. I have another foreach loop where I try to iterrate through the collection of LineItem in each Customer class.

The first foreach loop works correctly, but for some reason, I can't get into the second foreach loop.

Here is the Customer Class;

```
public class Customer
{
    public long customerId { get; set; }
    /* other properties */
    public List<LineItem> custLineItems = new List<LineItem>();
}
```

Here is the LineItem class:

```
public class LineItem
{
    public string packageDesc { get; set; }
    /* other properties */
}
```

Here is the code in main with the two foreach loops.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(Customer cust in customers)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText("Inside first foreach loop" + "\r\n");
        foreach (LineItem item in cust.custLineItems)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText("Inside second foreach loop" + "\r\n");
            textBox1.AppendText(item.packageDesc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `cust.custLineItems` is empty. Look for your error elsewhere.

Comment: "can't get into the second foreach loop"? You mean the code never executes? That would be because `cust.custLineItems` is always empty.

Comment: Use the debugger. Then show us the code where you fill the `custLineItems`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment...I think you guys are correct...the error is in the populating of LineItem.

Comment: You guys were right...I forgot this one line of code;

Comment: cust.addLineItem(lineItemHold);   I cant believe I have spent this much time and I missed this.  Thanks a million for your help!